# ITestContext#getAllTestMethods is empty when called from IModuleFactory

Tags: java, testng

I'm implementing TestNG's `IModuleFactory` with the goal of conditionally binding certain Guice `Module`s based on the test Classes/Methods being executed.

```java
class SomeModuleFactory : IModuleFactory {
  override fun createModule(iTestContext: ITestContext, aClass: Class<*>): Module {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have noticed that `iTestContext`'s fields (specifically `getAllTestMethods`) are not necessarily all available at `IModuleFactory#createModule` execution time and field availability is dependent on invocation method.

If I execute the test with `SomeModuleFactory` bound using `@Guice(moduleFactory)` from:

1. IntelliJ. Fields outside of `currentXmlTest` are not set yet set when `IModuleFactory#createModule` is executed BUT it is fully populated once any `@BeforeSuite` annotations are reached.
2. [Programmatically](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically). All fields are set to their final state when `IModuleFactory#createModule` is invoked.

Is there a reason `ITestContext` is in observable in an intermediary state from `IModuleFactory`?  Is there a way to force resolution of ITestContext?

Comment: I spent sometime looking at this and I am not sure I quite understand what you meant by the intermediate state. I was noticing that the `getAllTestMethods()` is ALWAYS empty while the Guice Module creation is underway because the method resolution happens ONLY after the test class instantiation part is sorted out. On a side note, would you be willing to file an issue with a reproducible sample at https://github.com/testng-team/testng ?